# Handling two document type

Tags: swift, macos, action, cfbundledocumenttypes

I'm developping a mac application that allow to transcribe/subtitles video. I must deal with two kind of document type:

- SRT file (read/write)
- Video file (read only)

For now SRT is the only document type of my application. I open video with an *Open a video...* menu item (under *File*), I connected to the *openVideo* action of the *First responder*.

Here is the code of my *VideoControlerView* called when pressing *Open a video...* :

```
@IBAction func openVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
    let dlg = NSOpenPanel()
    dlg.runModal()
    if let url = dlg.URL {
        self.playerView.player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    }
}
```

I'm sure it is possible to benefit from the multi document type handling of document based application but I can't figure how. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After questionning Apple Developer support about it, *DocumentType* is only designed for the editing document (SRT in my case).

The way I handle my asset (video file) is the proper way to go!